# JBoss support Websockets?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, websocket

Does JBoss support WebSockets?  Where can I find an example?

( I did try looking around for an answer, but ended up confused by product names.  There is something called [infinispan](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/InfinispanWebSocketServer) which might handle websockets, then there is [HornetQ](http://community.jboss.org/message/549847#549847) which might not be up to date, then there is a patch for [Netty](https://jira.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-264)...  I don't know what these different products are.  Maybe what I am trying to do is handled in Tomcat already?)

I just want some sample code so I can get a sense of how this type of connection would be handled by JBoss.  I would like to try to connect to some clients with [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) )

Comment: @Bozho -- the most recent version (6, right?) unless there is some websockety reason not t use the most recent version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss 6 supports asynchronous servlet handling. Websockets are on the client side. I guess they will work.

If you want to have comet regardless of the underlying implementation, take a look at [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net) - it will choose the most advanced method available.

Comment: for asynchronous servlet handling --> http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html

Comment: org.jboss.servlet.http.HttpEventServlet